# Missing ; before declaring object variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I can't figure out why the compiler is complaining about a missing semicolon before the first variable declaration. var convert {} 
Is this something to do with declaring objects?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        var convert { 
            "one" : 1,
            "two" : 2,
            "three" : 3,
            "four" : 4,
            "five" : 5,
            "six" : 6, 
            "seven" : 7,
            "eight" : 8,
            "nine" : 9, 
            "ten" : 10,
            "eleven" : 11,
            "twelve" : 12,
            "thirteen" : 13,
            "fourteen" : 14, 
            "fifteen" : 15
        };

        $('.downloadfile').click(function() { 
            $id = this.id; 
            $numberstrings = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten", "eleven", "twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen"];
            $length = $numberstrings.length;
            for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){ 
                if ($id.indexOf($numberstrings[$i]) != -1)
                {
                    $id = $numberstrings[$i];
                }
            }

            $id = convert[$id];
            window.alert($id);
            $filename = 'p'+$id+'.mp3';
            $.ajax({ url: 'download.php?argument=$filename'});



        });

    });
```

Comment: you need an `=` to initialize variables

Comment: Yikes I'm embarrassed to have missed that one. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed an `Equal To` operator.

```
var convert = {};
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo:

```
var convert { 
         ^^^^^
```

Missing `=`